# Extract fruit from image

Tags: python, opencv

I'am trying to find contour of a fruit within an image and filling it with black so i can either add it to another image or mask it.

However, as per the unexpected outcome image below, I'm only getting the contour without the filled color. This might be due to disconnected lines however i have tried to dilate my image and blur to resolve however unsuccessfully.
Any advise?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('/home/usr/Desktop/fruit.png')


image_edges = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)#
image_edges = cv2.GaussianBlur(image_edges,(3,3),1) #To connect broken lines
image_edges=cv2.Canny(image_edges,100,200)#Edge detection

image_edges=cv2.dilate(image_edges,(3,3),iterations=3)
image_edges=cv2.erode(image_edges,(3,3),iterations=3)


contours_draw, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image_edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)


mask = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)
mask.fill(255)
for c in contours_draw:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 100:  # greater the value, less detail will be shown
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), -1) 


mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


cv2.imshow('img', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

ORIGINAL IMAGE

[image]

UNEXPECTED RESULT:

[image]

Comment: the outline isn't closed. at the top there's a 1-pixel gap. -- why all the acrobatics, especially Canny, which more often makes the situation worse? simply *threshold*, you *have* a bright object on dark background.

Comment: Thanks. I'm preparing for next Olympics.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [grabCut algorithm](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html). The code in the linked tutorial works well if you can define a bounding rectangle around the object. In this case, you can determine a bounding box by thresholding with Otsu's algorithm and then using the `findNonzero` and `boundingRect` functions, like this:

```
_, img_mask = cv.threshold(img_edges, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY + cv.THRESH_OTSU)  
points = cv.findNonZero(img_mask)  
bounding_rect = cv.boundingRect(points)
```